# Service intent getaction and getextra return null

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, service

I have a really bad problem.
I have one notification service which works fine. When I test it works just fine I turn off/on 10 times to see if service failed or return null but it works fine. I also close application many time to see if its return null but it works fine.
but sometimes when I'm using my phone application show force close such as when I'm using other apps, crash system of firebase say getaction or intent is null.

What am I doing wrong?

crash system
[image]

[image]

this is my service code:

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    sp = getSharedPreferences("accdata", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    namesaveget = sp.getString("nameacc","No Account");
    int getwhattodo = intent.getIntExtra("service_call",0);
    if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null || getwhattodo == 0) {
        Log.e("receiver","service faild");
        Crashlytics.log("service faild to call");
        if (getwhattodo == 0) {
            stopSelf();
        }

    }
    if (intent != null && getwhattodo == 2) {
        Log.e("receiver","call done");
        createNotificationChannel();
        showMainNotification();
        showSubNotifications();
        Crashlytics.log("service call noti");
    }


    return START_STICKY;

}
```

this is my receiver that call my service:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("receiver","work");

    if (isNetworkConnected(context) == true) {


            Log.e("receiver","wifi on");
            Intent i = new Intent(context,ServiceNotifications.class);
            i.putExtra("service_call",2);
            context.startService(i);




    } else {
        Log.e("receiver","wifi off");
    }



}

public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context c) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

I also tried:
use start_stick service it won't work.
I'm trying use intent extra int instead of getaction but it didn't work either.

Comment: if you are not sure if intent is null or not but still you are making a call  int getwhattodo = intent.getIntExtra("service_call",0);
    if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null || getwhattodo == 0) {
        Log.e("receiver","service faild");
        Crashlytics.log("service faild to call");
        if (getwhattodo == 0) {
            stopSelf();
        }

    }

Comment: @ManojMohanty when i test app see if its return null it never return null i test 10 times it work fine i can see in android studio logcat but when i use my phone daily in time app force close so when i see in firebase its say null ref as you can see

Comment: to be frank I am not exactly sure why would that happen but if you see your code error returns a null intent and you are trying to use that null intent to perform further actions which might be causing the error its just one more check you can do

Comment: @ManojMohanty thanks for your suggestion but it despaired in random times when im not working  not when i test it(never return null)

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure if intent is null or not but still you are making a call just move int getwhattodo = intent.getIntExtra("service_call",0); call inside your null check

```
int getwhattodo = intent.getIntExtra("service_call",0);
    if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null || getwhattodo == 0) {
        Log.e("receiver","service faild");
        Crashlytics.log("service faild to call");
        if (getwhattodo == 0) {
            stopSelf();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This not about getwhattodo int when i use only getaction it have same problam. When i test it never return null. In random times it get null even i dont use my phone

Comment: i agree you never might get the error in your testing but there is a probability and that might be the reason I am just assuming :)

Comment: i dont know if it's have bug it despaired in random times when im playing games ir cheack my instagram or ... :D